# Почему выбор Ы/И в корне после приставок относят к фонетическому принципу письма?

Tags: фонетика

Наше письмо называют **фонематическим**, так как фонетическое чередование звуков в слабых позициях не отражается на письме, и морфемы сохраняют свой буквенный состав: вода ― водный, мороз ― морозы (этот принцип называют морфологическим, но основан он на фонематическом принципе).

**Фонетический принцип является исключением**: так, приставки на З/С мы пишем по слуху: истратил ―  измерил.

**Но при чем тут орфограмма Ы/И в корне слова после приставок на твердый согласный?** В русском языке есть парные варианты суффиксов и окончаний на Ы/И: рассматривать ― рассказывать (ЫВА/ИВА), столы ― земли (Ы/И).  Выбор Ы/И делается по слуху, но мы не считаем, что это фонетический принцип.

Такой же выбор делается и в корне (например: изымать ― взимать).

Comment: Чтобы не копировать весь материал сюда (он объемистый), читайте здесь.[Грамма.ру](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=3.7)

Comment: Окончания Ы/И, А/Я и т.д  - это тоже нарушение морфологического принципа и следование фонетическому принципу? Чем корень отличается от окончаний и суффиксов, которые пишутся по слуху?

Comment: Вы имеете в  виду ед. мн. число?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что большинство суффиксов и окончаний могут присоединяться к твердой или мягкой основе, поэтому они имеют твердый и мягкий письменные  варианты. Корень тоже имел бы такие варианты, если бы приставки были и твердыми, и мягкими. Но все приставки практически твердые (кроме взимать), и перед  корнем на И мы слышим естественный звук Ы и пишем букву Ы. Это нормально, но есть исключения, вот их и надо ОБЪЯСНЯТЬ.  А в этой статье почему-то вспоминают твердый знак, который к И никак не относится.  В общем, странная статейка.

Comment: Какие исключения, например?

Comment: Иноязычные слова (возможно, чтобы не искажать их корень), также после Ж и Х (чтобы избежать нехарактерных написаний ЖЫ, ХЫ): дезинфекция. межинститутский, сверхинтересный.

Answer (score 1):

Arina, а Вы к какому принципу эту орфограмму относите? К морфологическому? Традиционному?

У меня лично сомнений нет, что написание начального **ы** вместо **и** в корнях после **русскоязычных** приставок, оканчивающихся на твердый согласный (кроме приставок меж- и сверх- ): безыскусный, предыюльский, сызнова и т. п.происходит именно по фонетическому принципу.

Эти написания являются целиком и полностью фонетическими: как слышим, так и пишем.У меня что-то не открылась ссылка Сержа,может, один и тот же материал, который Вам не понравился:

Соблюдение морфологического принципа орфографии привело бы в данном случае к нарушению другого важнейшего принципа нашего письма - слогового принципа графики . Этот принцип предполагает, что в качестве единицы чтения и письма в русском языке выступает графический слог, т. е. что " сочетание согласной и гласной букв представляет цельный графический элемент, буквосочетание, обе части которого взаимно обусловлены: как гласные, так и согласные буквы пишутся и читаются с учетом соседних букв " [ Иванова В.Ф. Современный русский язык. Графика и орфография. М., 1976. С. 76-77 ].

В соответствии с этим принципом буква и , следующая за согласной, требует произносить эту согласную как мягкую. Однако согласно современной произносительной норме смягчения твердой согласной на конце приставок перед начальным и корня в действительности не происходит (ср. при ди - пре ды дущий, о би да - о бы грать ). Очевидно, русская графика могла бы в данном случае избрать и другой способ соблюдения слогового принципа: рекомендовать писать на стыке приставки и корня разделительный твердый знак (например, предъистория ) - аналогично тому, как употребляется эта графема на стыке приставок, оканчивающихся на твердый согласный, и корней, которые начинаются с гласных е, ё, ю, я , также требующих смягчения предыдущего согласного звука ( безъязыкий, сверхъестественный и т. п.). Однако, во-первых, такое написание выглядит куда более громоздким; во-вторых, буква и (в отличие от е, ё, ю, я ) в положении после твердого согласного никогда не обозначает двух звуков (ср. объедать и обедать - необходимость разделительного твердого знака в первом слове диктуется не только отсутствием смягчения согласного б , но и произношением на месте орфографического е сочетания двух звуков йэ ); в-третьих, значение может иметь и тот полузабытый исторический факт, что буква ы была рождена фантазией создателей нашего алфавита, Кирилла и Мефодия, именно как сочетание букв ъ и i [ Заметим походя: того самого i (и), о котором говорит известная поговорка "расставить точки над i " ].

Сохранение начального и в корне после приставок меж- и сверх- объясняется историческими причинами. Написание ы после приставки меж- прежде всего нарушило бы общее правило, известное с первого класса: " жи и ши всегда пиши через и ". Кроме того, историческая фонетика знает, что звуки ж и ш в русском языке в течение долгого времени были только мягкими (а не только твердыми, как ныне) [ О былой мягкости ж может напомнить современное произношение слов вожжи и дрожжи ].

С приставкой сверх- произошла совершенно обратная история: звук х на протяжении многих веков мог быть только твердым, так что при сочетании приставки сверх- и корня, начинающегося с и , в действительности не происходило никаких фонетических изменений, которые стоило бы отражать в графике (ср. правописание сложных слов, первая основа которых заканчивается на и : трехимпульсный, четырехигольный ).

Происхождение корня - русский он или иноязычный - в этом правиле не учитывается, хотя до выхода в свет ныне действующего орфографического свода (1956 года) ы вместо этимологического и после приставок писалось только в русских корнях, а в корнях заимствованных и сохранялось ( раз ы грать, но без и дейный ). Однако такое разграничение вряд ли можно считать целесообразным, так как в современном языке такие слова, как идея, история, интерес и многие другие, уже не воспринимаются как иноязычные.

После иноязычных приставок, оканчивающихся на согласную ( дез-, контр-, пан-, пост-, суб-, супер-, транс- ), и сохраняется для того, чтобы пишущий мог быстрее увидеть границу между частями слова и благодаря этому быстрее понять их значение. Вследствие этого подхода (при котором учитывается происхождение приставки, но не корня) по-разному выглядит начальная буква корня в таких, например, парах, как пост и мпрессионистский - пред ы мпрессионистский или контр и гра - роз ы грыш .

Особое внимание следует обратить на глагол взимать , в котором исконно русская приставка вз , оканчивающаяся на твердый согласный, присоединяется к древнерусскому глаголу имать ' брать ', однако в начале корня сохраняется буква и , так как такое написание соответствует произношению (ср. взи мать , но из ы мать ).

Кроме того, следует помнить, что правило о переходе и в ы после приставок не распространяется на сложносокращенные слова: спорт и нвентарь, гос и нспекция, но это тоже в соответствии с произношением, сложные слова мы произносим с двумя ударениями,с паузой.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо за ответ, но это как раз тот материал, который  мне не понравился.  Меня интересует вот что: выбор парных гласных в окончаниях и суффиксах - это тоже фонетический принцип? Он же ничем не отличается от выбора Ы/И в корне: тоже как слышим, так и пишем. Конечно, может быть, всё дело в терминологии, и к фонетическому принципу можно отнести разные ситуации. Для меня фонетический принцип - это выбор буквы в СЛАБЫХ позициях ПО СЛУХУ. Именно такой принцип противопоставлен морфологическому принципу и определяет тип письма - фонематическое или фонетическое.

Comment: Фонетический принцип касается только орфограмм, а ы/и в суффиксах не орфограмма, это естественный выбор, соответствующий слоговому принципу письма, там орфограмма - падежные окончания с выбором между ы-и/ о-е.

Comment: Тогда как ы/и в корнях после приставок на согласный - орфограмма, там приходится выбирать, используя правило: "как слышим, так и пишем, кроме приставок сверх-,меж- и иноязычных"

Comment: А к морфологическому это уж никак не относится, если меняется написание корня

Comment: Вот пример: играть - сыгранный, после твердой приставки по слуху пишется Ы. Корень ИГР/ЫГР такой же вариант, как суффикс ЫВА/ИВА, окончание Ы/И. Мы же не говорим, что меняется окончание, просто по правилам графики имеем два варианта письма после твердых и мягких согласных. Чем корень отличается от других морфем?  А исключения - это только частные случаи, их могло бы и не быть. Выбор Ы/И в корне - это орфограмма, которая должна объяснять только  эти частные случаи, а они как раз и не соответствуют фонетическому письму.

Comment: Я что-то не пойму, против чего Вы протестуете: против того, что это вообще орфограмма, или против того, что она объясняется фонетическим принципом? Если делают ошибки (пишут "предиюльский, прединфарктный"), значит, орфограмма. А объясняется она очень верно: как слышим, так и пишем (а не так, как пишется этот корень без приставки, если бы по морфологическому принципу),  объясняются и частные случаи, не попадающие под этот принцип, - иноязычные приставки и сверх-, меж-, произносимые твёрдо,но после них пишется И в соответствии с историческими традициями.

Comment: Людмила, да я не протестую, просто думала, что кто-нибудь поймёт сказанное. Это орфограмма, так как (в связи с исключениями)  надо делать выбор. Но это не фонетическая орфограмма, а отклонение от графической нормы написания парных гласных Ы/И в корне, причем касается она нескольких слов.  Просто не стоит путать фонетические написания в слабых позициях  с общими правилами письма при обозначении мягкости-твердости согласных, хотя парные гласные в этом случае  тоже пишутся по слуху.

Comment: Нет,Arina, никто ничего не путает, фонетическое написание(орфограммы по фонетическому принципу) и слоговой принцип графики действуют одновременно, один другому не противопоставлены, а приводятся в соответствие друг с другом, потому Вас и не понимают на сайте. Если , как Вы предлагаете, всё объяснять слоговым принципом, ещё больше запутаете школьников, его не все студенты до конца понимают, не могут найти нарушения, гораздо легче сказать: как слышим, так и пишем.

Comment: Наши школьники понимают высшую математику, но почему-то "не понимают" элементарные вещи из русского языка.  Вот последний вопрос: страна/земля, это выбор А/Я, и делается он  по слуху. Так  это графика (правила письма при обозначении мягкости-твердости согласных) , фонетическая орфограмма или что это?

Comment: Ну, это они понимают: йотированная буква в этой позиции обозначает мягкость предыдущего согласного. Это просто графика, но ведь И-не йотированная буква, приходится вспоминать, что Ы - это i +ъ,  положение после приставки - это не то, что на конце слова, там же Ъ перед йотированными, так что не всё так просто, как в других позициях.

Comment: Зачем всё так усложнять? Есть графическая система, одинаковая для всех морфем. Если забыть про исключения, то мы имеем  обычную графику для корня, как и для других частей слова:  есть окончание Ы/И и есть корень ЫГР/ИГР. Если не  было бы исключений, то и не было бы орфограммы вообще. А исключения - просто отклонения от графический написаний, так и надо их называть. Так что графическая это орфограмма, а не фонетическая. Впрочем, я совершенно не настаиваю, это мое мнение. Просто хотелось понять аргументы  людей, называющих эту орфограмму фонетической и абсолютно не сомневающихся, что это так.