# Как объяснить правило выбора Ы/И после приставок?

Tags: орфография, заимствования, приставка

Правило всем известное 
http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=35#pp35

1. После приставок, оканчивающихся на согласную, в корне вместо начального И пишется буква Ы в соответствии с произношением: ***подыграть,  безыдейный.***
2. После приставок меж- и сверх- в начале корня сохраняется буква И (так как по общему правилу после шипящих и заднеязычных буква Ы не пишется): ***межинститутский,  сверхизысканный***.
3. После иноязычных приставок и частиц дез-, контр-, пост-, суб-, супер-, транс-, пан- буква И в начале корня сохраняется: ***дезинформация, контригра, постимпрессионизм, субинспектор.***

Как мы видим, выбор И после Ж и Х **объясняется**, но не объясняется ситуация с иноязычными приставками. **А если корень иноязычный, а приставка русская?** Может быть, и в этом случае надо писать букву И?

На эти мысли наводит запись слова ***безынтернетный***, которая смотрится не лучшим образом.

Comment: Sharon, сейчас не могу ответить, прочитайте о фонетическом принципе. Насколько я помню, эта тема поднималась на нашем форуме.

Comment: Там вроде бы  обсуждался вопрос о том, к какому орфографическому принципу относится эта орфограмма (есть такое упражнение для учащихся). Довольно бесполезное занятие, так как четких определений по этой теме нет.

Comment: `... запись слова «безынтернетный», которая смотрится не лучшим образом` — почему не лучшим? В этом слове отчётливо слышны *твёрдая [з]* и, как результат, *[ы]*, так что *и* на письме там попросту неоткуда взяться. Кстати, мне это напомнило про *ча-ща*, где для получения протяжного *[я]* (вместо обрубка при переходе от мягкого согласного к *а*) также нужно постараться.

Comment: Почему для иноязычных приставок делается исключение - вот о чем был вопрос, но почему-то никто не отвечает на него. Например, слова  контригра и отыграть  пишутся по-разному.  Они произносятся тоже по-разному или здесь другая причина? В слове дезинформация произносится звук И?

Comment: Sharon, на один из таких вопросов отвечал я.Помнится, вы тоже принимали участие. Завтра постараюсь объязательно ответить. Сегодня, к сожалению, не могу.

Comment: Помнится, да. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434563/Почему-выбор-Ы-И-в-корне-после-приставок-относят-к-фонетическому-принципу-письма Сказано там много, но думаю, что речь шла не о причине исключений для Ы/И.

Comment: А о чем же? Там же сказано: чтобы не нарушить слогового принципа графики.

Comment: Серж, слова с русскими и иноязычными приставками находятся в одинаковых фонетических условиях. в том числе и по отношению к слоговому письму. Тогда почему они пишутся по-разному?

Comment: Там и это написано.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, почитаю.

Comment: @Sharon В слове дезинформация произносится звук И? – Локально, бывает, человек, живущий на юге, так и произнесет. София Ротару поет:"Время стрессоВИстрастей". И не только в южнорусских регионах, такое можно услышать и на севере, и за Уралом.  В средней России  такое бывает редко.

Answer (score 2):

Есть достаточно словарных "русско-нерусских" прецедентов:

**Безынтеллектуальный, безынициативный, безынтересный**...

Answer (score 1):

Это правило легко проиллюстрировать словами "предынфарктное состояние" и "постинфарктное". Думаю, комментарии не нужны

Comment: «Бодры» надо говорить бодрее... «Как объяснить правило», а не чем проиллюстрировать, — был вопрос. «Почему для иноязычных приставок делается исключение - вот о чем был вопрос», – Sharon.

Answer (score 1):

Прочитала я статью, где  объясняется выбор Ы/И в корне. http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=3.7

И вот какое впечатление.

1) В статье называются такие принципы письма, как морфологический (фонематический), фонетический, слоговой.

Вот только **фонетический принцип** может иметь два значения. Во-первых, **вся русская речь фонетическая и слоговая**. Слог образуют согласный и следующий за ним гласный, которые произносятся слитно, влияя друг на друга. Условно можно сказать, что, к примеру, ла и ля — это твердый и мягкий слоги (хотя считается, что в них один и тот же гласный звук А, но мягкий Л и твердый Л). Это произношение отражено на письме парными буквами А — Я, О — Ё, У — Ю, Э — Е, Ы — И.

**Примечание.** Во втором значении фонетический принцип связан со слабыми позициями звуков и противопоставлен морфологическому (фонематическому) принципу. Так, З на конце приставок может  произноситься как З или С, и это в виде исключения отражается на письме. Но этого принципа в этой теме мы касаться не будем.

**Итак, Ы пишется после твердых согласных, И — после мягких.** Всегда, для всех морфем, включая корень. Это не орфограмма, это основная фонетика. Практически все приставки заканчиваются на твердый согласный (искл. — взимать), поэтому после приставки в корне пишется буква Ы (сравнить суффикс ИН/ЫН, окончание Ы/И).

2) **Слоговое письмо нарушать нельзя, но иногда можно.** Исключений вполне достаточное количество, для каждого в статье **придумана причина**. ***Межиздательский***: как-то неудобно писать ЖИ, ведь ЖИ — ШИ пиши через И. ***Сверхинтересный***: тут надо подумать; но вот Х всегда был твердый (на протяжении многих веков!), зачем обозначать его твердость. ***Иноязычные приставки:*** это чтобы лучше увидеть границу между малознакомой приставкой и русским корнем. ***Сложносокращенные слова:***  то же самое, чтобы границы различать.

3) **А иноязычные корни разве не надо хорошо различать?** Тоже бы надо, вот до 1956 года писали ***безидейный*** и др., но потом слова *идея, интерес, история* перестали восприниматься как иноязычные.

4) **И выводы:** 1) Исключений более чем достаточно. 2) Слоговой принцип — не священная корова и  нарушается без особо важных причин (буква И пишется скорее по традиции уже существующего письма, чем в соответствии с этими объяснениями).

Так неужели для иноязычного слова ***интернет*** не найдется местечка на скамейке для исключений? **Почему бы нам  не писать "безинтернетный"?** Уж очень не хочется искажать ИНТЕРНЕТ, учитывая, что существует всем известный формант ИНТЕР (между), входящий во многие  слова.

**ИНТЕРНЕТ**, происходит от английского Internet (букв. «межсетевой»), сокр. от internetwork, далее из inter- «между» + network «сеть». Термин Internet был официально введён в США в 1974 г.

Comment: Sharon, согласен с вами по поводу написания; безинтернетный. А разве есть написание этого слова через ы? Вполне, думаю можно писать через и.

Comment: Серж, этот вопрос недавно обсуждался https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449960/ОБЕЗЫНТЕРНЕТЧЕН-Интернет-корневое-Т-сохраняется/449963#449963

Comment: Да, писать можно все что угодно.Но надо учитывать, что слово международное. Поэтому, чтобы сохранить графический облик слова, думаю можно писать через и.

Comment: Серж, хотелось бы так писать. Но в словаре слова еще нет, а формально оно попадает под общее правило, так как не относится к исключениям.

Comment: Sharon, на мой взгляд, нельзя сказать, что слово обрусело. Это международное слово. Думаю, исключение можно сделать.

Comment: В личных записях исключение можно сделать, а если Вы редактируете книгу, то как быть? Там нужно строгое соответствие правилам.

Comment: Sharon, но ведь вы и сами прекрасно знаете, что были исключения. В любом случае, я задал вопрос Грамме.ру. Научный руководитель портала член орфографической комиссии.  Посмотрим, что они ответят.

Comment: Хорошо, Серж, спасибо. Интересно, что они ответят.

Comment: @ Sharon, они ответили, что надо писать через ы. Безынтернетный.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж. Впрочем, я не сомневалась, что так ответят. Общий закон действует, а для этого слова никто специальных исключений делать не будет.  Это основная причина, а вовсе не рассказы о нарушении слогового письма в данном конкретном случае.

Comment: Да, они сказали, что хотя слово в словаре не зафиксировано, тем не менее следует писать в соответствии  с правилом.